# .NET (WinForms) Grid Control with Collapse/Expand Capabilities

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0

Anybody purchased/used a DataGrid/GridView control that allows Collapsing/Expanding  Parent-Child relationships?

The standard DataGrid control, which I am using in .NET 2.0, seems to have limited capabilities with regards to this functionality.  The newer GridView control doesn't support this at all to my knowledge.

I was thinking about developing a custom control but that could get expensive for my client..

I need this control for WinForms (not ASP.NET)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

We've used [Janus Grids](http://www.janusys.com/janus/library/CustomPages/gridexnet.htm) here for years, very powerful, but have recently started using [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com/) controls on new products . . . they seem to be even better (but *I* haven't used them much at all yet).

Both should give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Xceed do a very full featured library for these.
There are [WPF](http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_New.html) and [WinForms](http://xceed.com/Grid_WinForms_Intro.html) implementations.

I have had a lot of success with older versions, I haven't upgraded in a while though.

The parent child aspect is fully customizable and can go to arbitrary[1] depths.

[1] well int.MaxValue but you'd never get there

Answer (score 1):

The [NOV Grid for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-grid-control-overview.aspx) (available for WinForms and WPF) includes a TableGrid and a TreeGrid. The Tree Grid Self-referencing produces a tree-like structure from a tabular data source.

The Grid component can be used in projects targeting .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 or higher. It is also available as Portable Class Library (PCL).

Full disclosure - I work at Nevron

Answer (score 0):

[VIBlend](http://www.viblend.com) has a hierarchical grid control which will likely address your needs. It's a WinForms implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Look at 10Tec's WinForms Grid iGrid. Here is the article from the 10Tec website related to your question: http://10tec.com/articles/treeview-in-datagridview.aspx