# Showing hierarchical data in winforms datagrid

Tags: winforms, datagridview, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Am working on a .net 3.5/Winforms application.
I need to show a datagridview with hierarchical data in the datagrid.

For example, master rows will have an expand/collapse icon...and when the user clicks on a master row, it should expand and show the child row details in the grid.

Using the Infragistics sample example at http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=1665, am now able to see Master/Child data in my ultragrid.

Now my  next task is to :

1.Show editable textboxes in the child grid having order details.[Note: I tried this but did not work for me: this.ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[3].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.Edit;]

2.When the user hits submit button, read these textbox values and push it to the database.

Could you please let me know if this is possible and how to go about it?

Any sample example will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: To get editing to work, can you try this.ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[3].CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit?  This will tell the grid that you want it to go into edit mode when the user clicks on the cell(s) in question.

Comment: Thanks PaulF, but it didnt work.Even if it does, my requirement is to show the cells as textboxes[and hence editable] after the form load is complete.This would be more intuitive from the usability point of view rather than making the user know that the cell is editable only when he clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

[.NET (WinForms) Grid Control with Collapse/Expand Capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532335/net-winforms-grid-control-with-collapse-expand-capabilities)

**EDIT:**:

For **Infragistics UltraGrid**, refer

http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/14615/

Comment: Hi, i have never used infragistics.but do they use term Wingrid for datagrid ? or ultragrid ?

Comment: Hi,jimmy..just edited the answer..plz check this out. regards

Comment: Have edited my question.Could you please have a look at it and respond incase u have some inputs.Thanks.